# Finding the names of the duplicate values in an Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns of data that I am checking against, both of them contain names. Example:

```
Name1           Name 2
John Smith      John Smit
Bill Burr       Billy Burr
Mike Jones      Mike Jones
```

I need to find which names match and which names are partially matched. in order to do this i used the add-in Fuzzy Lookup to see where their were partial matches and created a column with the numbers, i then made a function to show which was a match and which was a partial match:

```
=IF(C2=1,"MATCH",IF(C2=0,"NO MATCH","PARTIAL"))
```

Following that i then calculated the number of matches, no matches and partial lists using this function

```
=COUNTIF(G:G,"MATCH") -- And so on
```

**PROBLEM!**

This approach is good for finding the number but i want to show which names are duplicates, this is were i am struggling

Going by the data i have retrieved I can see that there are Matches and Partial Matches but now i want to actually show those names

What can i use to achieve this

Comment: Filter on `MATCH` in Column G then copy and paste Column A.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you Scott, Do you have a formula that does that?

Comment: To do it in one formula would require an array formula INDEX/MATCH, or you can use a helper column and a regular INDEX/MATCH.  There are many examples on this site alone.  Search Return Multiple Vlookup or INDEX/MATCH and you should find many.

Comment: @Thanks, if you post this as an answer i will accept it